# MySQL: insert procedure, with variable from another table

Tags: mysql, insert, where-clause, procedure

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE userTypes (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    type VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE users (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    userTypeId INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (userTypeId) REFERENCES userTypes(id)
);
  
INSERT INTO userTypes (id, type) VALUES (0, 'free');
INSERT INTO userTypes (id, type) VALUES (1, 'paid');
```

I want to create a procedure where that it inserts a user in the users table, with :

- id is auto incremented.
- email is equal to the email parameter.
- userTypeId is the id of the userTypes row whose type attribute is equal to the type parameter

The `INSERT` function doesn't work with `WHERE`, so I tried to add a `UPDATE` but it's not working. Here's what I have for the moment:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE insertUser(
    IN type VARCHAR(50),
    IN email VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO users(id, email, userTypeID) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), email, userTypeID);
    UPDATE users SET users.userTypeID = usertypes.id
WHERE usertypes.type = type;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

The expected result should be something like this:

```
CALL insertUser('free', 'name_1@mail.com');
CALL insertUser('paid', 'name_2@mail.com');

SELECT * FROM users;


id    email                   userTypeId
------------------------------------------
1     name_1@mail.com         0
2     name_2@mail.com         1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave out the auto_increment-column. As the name suggests, the db will fill this automatically.

Then, use different names for the parameters than the column names. You can use a prefix with the parameters.

Additionally, you could consider using the `userTypeId` integer value as parameter instead of the textual value. Otherwise you need to handle the situation where the passed type is not among the types in the `userTypes` (create a new one/reject insert).

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE insertUser(
in_type VARCHAR(50),
in_email VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN

INSERT INTO users(email, userTypeID) 
SELECT in_email, id
FROM userTypes
WHERE type=in_type;

IF (ROW_COUNT()=0) THEN
  SELECT 'Error';
ELSE
  SELECT 'OK';
END IF;
  
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You might also handle the situation where there are duplicates in the userTypes type column, since there seems to be no unique constraint on that column. If there were, your insert would do multiple inserts.

Comment: As said, it would be better to use the `userTypeId` as a parameter to the routine than the actual name for it.